# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'avoriaz'

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, avoriaz

I'm new to Vue and am learning how to test it from [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-write-a-unit-test-for-vuejs).  I've reached the end of the tutorial but am getting a strange error on the last step of using `avoriaz`:

```
ERROR in ./test/unit/specs/list.spec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'avoriaz' in 
'/local/path/to/vuejs-
testing/test/unit/specs'
 @ ./test/unit/specs/list.spec.js 3:15-33
 @ ./test/unit/specs \.spec$
 @ ./test/unit/index.js
```

Here's the relevant code in my test file:

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz';
import List from '@/components/List';
import Vue from 'vue';
...
```

And my `package.json` file:

```
  ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "avoriaz": "^2.6.3",
  ...
```

I tried removing my `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` and reinstalling everything with `npm install` to no avail.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author of avoriaz here. This was a bug with avoriaz 2.6.3, it's fixed in 2.6.5.

The problem was I switched the way the file was exported. This caused problems for most users.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Avoriaz for a while, and also have encountered the same issue since the latest update since yesterday.

I believe it's caused by same bugs in the module itself. Submitted an issue to their Github repo already.

Edited: problem fixed by author in version 2.6.5